# How to convert a Option<Result<T, Error>> to an Option<T> without unwrapping it?

Tags: rust

I am trying to find a good way to convert an `Option<String>` to an `Option<i8>`.

For example,

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let some_option: Option<String> = Some("too".to_owned()); 
    let new_option: Option<i8> = some_option.map(|x| i8::from_str(x.as_str())); 
}
```

I thought I could use the turbo fish to explicitly cast the type so something like this:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let some_option: Option<String> = Some("too".to_owned()); 
    let new_option: Option<i8> = some_option.map::<Option<i8>>(|x| i8::from_str(x.as_str())); 
}
```

However, the compiler points out this isn't the correct amount of parameters, so I thought this might work, but it doesn't:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let some_option: Option<String> = Some("too".to_owned()); 
    let new_option: Option<i8> = some_option.map::<Option<i8>,i8::from_str>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ok()` and `unwrap_or()` functions:

```
fn test() -> Option<Result<u32, ()>> {
    Some(Ok(1))
}

fn main() {
    let x: Option<Result<_, _>> = test();
    println!("{:?}", x.map(|r| r.ok()).unwrap_or(None));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating an `Option<Result<T, E>>` in the first place, you can combine:

1. [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then), which applies a closure that returns an `Option` and flattens the result.
2. [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok), which converts a `Result` to an `Option`, discarding the error.

```
fn main() {
    let some_option = Some("too".to_owned()); 
    let new_option = some_option.and_then(|x| x.parse::<u8>().ok()); 
}
```

You can use the same two tools to answer your direct question:

```
fn convert<T, E>(a: Option<Result<T, E>>) -> Option<T> {
    a.and_then(Result::ok)
}
```